# getJSON doesn't return anything in firefox extension

Tags: jquery, firefox, firefox-addon, getjson, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to write a firefox extension using jquery to get data from the wikipedia API. I call getJSON like this:

```
jqxhr = $.getJSON("http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?", {page:wikipediaPage, prop:"text|images", uselang:"en"}, function() {dump("success?\n");} ).error(function() { dump("error?\n"); } );
```

This code is being executed, because the script doesn't stop running and I don't see an exception, but there is no response either from the success or error functions. The code works when I put it in an HTML doc on my computer and run that from the browser, but in the extension it fails.

I'm totally new to javascript and jquery, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is code that works when loaded as a webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        a.test {font-weight : bold; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <div id="insertTest"></div>

    <script>
        var wikipediaHTMLResult = function(data) {
            document.write("<p>Inside callback</p>");
            document.write("Text data: " + data);
            var readData;
            for(x in data){
                for(y in data[x]){
                    for(z in data[x][y]){
                        readData += data[x][y][z];
                    }
                }
            }
            var arrayData = jQuery.makeArray(readData);
            var newData = new Array();
            var ignore = false;
            //document.write("<p>" + readData + "</p>");
            var i = 0;
            //document.write(arrayData);
            for(x in readData){
                if(i > 100000){
                    break;
                }
                i++;
                if(readData[x]=== '<'){
                    ignore = true;
                }
                else if(readData[x] === '>'){
                    ignore = false;
                }
                else if(readData[x]==='"'){
                    if(ignore){
                        newData[x] = "";
                    }
                    else{
                        newData[x] = "&quot;";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    if(ignore){
                        newData[x] = "";
                    }
                    else{
                        newData[x] = readData[x];
                    }
                }
            }
            i = 0;
            for(x in newData){
                document.write(newData[x]);
                i++;
            }
            document.write("<p>"+i+"</p>");
        };
        function callWikipediaAPI(wikipediaPage) {
            $.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?', {page:wikipediaPage, prop:'text|images', uselang:'en'}, wikipediaHTMLResult);
        }
        callWikipediaAPI('Gregg Hartsuff');


        $("a").addClass("test");
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                $(this).hide("slow");
            });
        });
        document.write("<p>Script is running</p>");
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Do you have a running example?

Comment: Have you firebugged this to see that the request is being made and is returning a response?

Comment: How would I do that? I've never used firebug.

Comment: @Ian firebug is an extension for Firebug. You can download within your Firefox. You can inspect elements, monitor your network and debug your JavaScript codes.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, I was interested in seeing what the API would return so I whipped up a quick example. You can see the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/ZPNxv/

Also, you should definitely look into [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) as it will help you debug this a lot easier. You can just run the request right from firebug (and see what it returns).

```
var url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&callback=?";
var page = "baseball"

$.getJSON(url, { 
  page: page, 
  prop:"text|images", 
  uselang:"en"
}, function(data) {
  var $container = $("body")

  // append title
  $container.append(data['parse']['title']);

  // append page text
  $container.append(data['parse']['text']['*']);    

  // append images
  var images = data['parse']['images'];
  $.each(images, function(i, src){
    // note: the path of these images is somewhat obscured
    // filenames are all that is supplied (no path)
    $container.append(src)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

YES!
I have seen this too and found absolutely nothing online about it either.
I was using php to return JSOn results and found that changing 'Content-Type' using header() helped but strangely not every single time i'd say 95% of the time.

Also make sure that your JSON is valid, copy and paste the response into here if in doubt as jQuery Firebug simply does nothing otherwise:
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Hope that helps